# Ruby: Rest-client multipart upload to Google drive with metadata

Tags: ruby, rest, drive

I am trying to perform a file upload to google drive's API using Rest calls. The API says that if you want to name the file metadata must be passed and it should be uploaded as multipart.

I am getting a '400 Bad Request' error. I think that this might be due to having multiple content types using Rest client.

```
RestClient::Request.execute(
                               :method => "post",
                               :url => "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart",
                               :headers => {:Authorization => "Bearer #{access_token}", :content_type => 'multipart/related'},
                               :payload => {:metadata => "{'title' : 'testing'}", :file => File.new(file, 'rb'), :multipart => true}
                           )
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I get the exact same error.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, using the given library (rest-client), this is not possible as the request, according to Google's requirements, the multi-parts need to be ordered and must have the correct mime type for each of the multipart.

So, I'd say, the syntax you've used is closest to correct, but unfortunately the gem doesn't seem to support this [1] as of the time of this comment.

If you still are looking for a solution, the closest thing I found was digging directly into Google's API client library, where they hand-craft a multipart request with the help of hurley [2].

You can check the source code for some ideas.[3]

Hope this helps.

[1] https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/pull/222

[2] https://github.com/lostisland/hurley

[3] https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/d2e51b4e7d4cb5a18cb08b2aed9c0d8ffff14b22/lib/google/apis/core/multipart.rb